# SpringBoot3 SpringWebflux and GraphQL throws No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using SpringBoot3 (3.1.5). My app is reactive based with spring-boot-starter-webflux and spring-boot-starter-graphql on the path (Maven). When I call GraphQL (GraphiQL or Postman), I get an exception saying No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context1. I am not able to solve it.
Also , I cannot upgrade to a higher version of Spring Boot at this point of time.

My dependency hierarchy.

[image]